# Referencing current dialog in ExtJS from a CQ5 component dialog

Tags: extjs, aem

I'm new to CQ5 and ExtJS and this is my scenario:

I created a new component with its own dialog for authoring. In the dialog I added a checkbox field with a custom xtype that I created. What I want to do is this:

Whenever the checkbox is checked/unchecked, I want to dynamically add/remove a TAB to the existing dialog to show further authoring options.

I've seen how to handle ExtJS' Window and TabPanel but I can't figure out how to get the reference of the dialog I'm in so that I can manipulate it (add/remove tabs).

I tried CQ.Ext.WindowMgr.getActive() to see if that gets me my window/dialog but it's not giving me what I expect.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to add listener(s) to your field.
http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/developing/widgets.html#Dynamic Dialogs

You should be able to use this.findParentByType to find the parent dialog.